# GC::Profiler.enable in JRuby

Tags: jruby

I am trying to profile my app to see where I can tweak memory management and speed. I have read into Garbage collection and I am trying to use

```
GC::Profiler.enable
```

In my app. However when I call this in Jruby I am getting a

```
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized
```

I know that the garbage collection is done in the JVM on Jruby - so this might be why it is not initialized Which makes sense, what is the alternative to use in Jruby?

Answer (score 3):

That's a MRI specific API - there's not an API equivalent for JRuby probably due the way the JVM works (there are multiple GC strategies with most VMs and there's no consistent API to work with the GC, even a `System.gc()` call does not necessary trigger garbage-collection immediately).

But there's a standart monitoring API (called **MX**) available for Java applications and since your JRuby app is a Java app you can use those, of course you might need to understand some of the internals e.g. how your ruby classes are seen by the JVM, but it ain't that hard.

Try starting here: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/monitoring-the-jvm-heap-with-jruby/

Here's a summary of Java tools available you can use with JRuby as well: http://blog.headius.com/2010/07/browsing-memory-jruby-way.html

Don't forget to check the wiki as well, e.g. there's a page on profiling object allocations: 
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Profiling-Object-Allocations

Comment: thank you for the comment, really helpful - i think the outcome will be a mixture of all of the above. Brilliant though that I can see such detail in an application!